# Image photo gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created a image photo gallery.

I styled it coming up and down as I click on the next and prev button

I need it to come side by side as I click on prev and next.

here it is demo

http://jsfiddle.net/T657N/16/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just changed the `top` parameter to `left` inside the script.

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/T657N/18/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to just change the SwapFirstLast() function of your javascript:

Replace

```
 $(this).animate({ 'top' : direction + $(this).height() + 'px' }, 'slow', function() { //animate the img above/under the gallery (assuming all pictures are equal height)
  $(this).css('z-index', newZindex) //set new z-index
    .animate({ 'top' : '0' }, 'slow', function() { //animate the image back to its original position
      inAnimation = false; //reset the flag
    });
});
```

with

```
 $(this).animate({ 'left' : direction + $(this).height() + 'px' }, 'slow', function() { //animate the img above/under the gallery (assuming all pictures are equal height)
  $(this).css('z-index', newZindex) //set new z-index
    .animate({ 'left' : '0' }, 'slow', function() { //animate the image back to its original position
      inAnimation = false; //reset the flag
    });
});
```

so finally your function will be:

```
function swapFirstLast(isFirst) {
if(inAnimation) return false; //if already swapping pictures just return
else inAnimation = true; //set the flag that we process a image

var processZindex, direction, newZindex, inDeCrease; //change for previous or next image

if(isFirst) { processZindex = z; direction = '-'; newZindex = 1; inDeCrease = 1; } //set variables for "next" action
else { processZindex = 1; direction = ''; newZindex = z; inDeCrease = -1; } //set variables for "previous" action

$('#pictures img').each(function() { //process each image
  if($(this).css('z-index') == processZindex) { //if its the image we need to process
    $(this).animate({ 'left' : direction + $(this).height() + 'px' }, 'slow', function() { //animate the img above/under the gallery (assuming all pictures are equal height)
      $(this).css('z-index', newZindex) //set new z-index
        .animate({ 'left' : '0' }, 'slow', function() { //animate the image back to its original position
          inAnimation = false; //reset the flag
        });
    });
  } else { //not the image we need to process, only in/de-crease z-index
    $(this).animate({ 'top' : '0' }, 'slow', function() { //make sure to wait swapping the z-index when image is above/under the gallery
      $(this).css('z-index', parseInt($(this).css('z-index')) + inDeCrease); //in/de-crease the z-index by one
    });
  }
});

return false; //don't follow the clicked link
```

}

Hope it will help you.